# How can I kill all my functions after execution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I have a condition `column == 1` and if this is the case, the function `MakeCellsEditable` and the function `myCallbackFunction` are initialized:

```
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ejbeaty/CellEdit/master/js/dataTables.cellEdit.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
    $('#myTable tbody').on('mousedown', 'td', function () {
        $('#myTable').data('column', table.cell(this).index().columnVisible);
    });
    if (column == 1) {
       table.MakeCellsEditable({
           "onUpdate": myCallbackFunction
       });
    }
});

function myCallbackFunction(updatedCell, updatedRow, oldValue) {
    var array = updatedRow.data();
    var id = array[0];
    var column = $('#myTable').data('column');
    console.log("The column is: " + column);
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "update.php",
        data: {
            updatedCell: updatedCell.data(),
            id: id,
            column: column,
        },
        cache: false
    });
}
```

What I want to do is, after the functions are executed, I want to kill them. Because otherwise if I one time clicked column 1, then all my tables are editable (not only column 1).
I tried `table.unbind();` or `table.die()`, but this didn't work out.

---

I tested at the end of the code:

```
 function destroyTable() {
        if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#myTable')) {
            table.destroy();
            table.MakeCellsEditable("destroy");
        }
    }
```

But it didn't work out

Comment: have you read https://github.com/ejbeaty/CellEdit ? `table.MakeCellsEditable("destroy");`

Comment: Oh haven't seen this!!

Comment: But I tested `table.MakeCellsEditable("destroy");` it unfortunately didn't work out

Comment: Give @Lashane some time to post it as an answer, so you can accept it. If he/she doesn't do it, you can answer it yourself and accept that answer.

Comment: ok, I will do that, I anyway didn't get it work until now

Comment: what about: $('#myTable tbody').off('mousedown') ?

Comment: @gaetanoM I placed `$('#myTable tbody').off('mousedown') ` right after the if condition. Now if I click any column (except column 1), then no columns are editable anymore. If I click for the first time on column 1 then all my columns are editable

Comment: @gaetanoM If I place it after the mousedown function, then no column is editable anymore

Comment: found a solution `table.MakeCellsEditable({"columns": [1],});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question in the headline: Yep:

```
function thiswilljustworkonce(){
 alert("once");
this.thiswilljustworkonce=function(){};
}

thiswilljustworkonce();
thiswilljustworkonce();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `columns` option for CellEdit plugin to specify which column needs to be editable. There would be no need to remove event handler.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

function myCallbackFunction (updatedCell, updatedRow, oldValue) {
    console.log("The new value for the cell is: " + updatedCell.data());
    console.log("The values for each cell in that row are: " + updatedRow.data());
}

table.MakeCellsEditable({
    "columns": [0],
    "onUpdate": myCallbackFunction,
    "confirmationButton": true
});
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/kesv478v/) for code and demonstration.